# How do I remove Podcasts from IOS Podcast app

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, applications, memory

I've been using the IOS Podcast app and I'm trying to remove podcast from it. I had subscribed to a podcast, but now I unsubscribed and deleted the episodes. It still shows up in my podcast menu though. How do I remove it from the list of my podcasts?

Also, It does not show up on my podcast list on my mac iTunes, so I can't delete from there. Any ideas?

It's not a huge deal, but I download and try a ton of podcasts and the list builds up quick with podcasts I use and a bunch that I no longer listen to.

Comment: Have you tried checking in Settings->general->usage, (wait for all your apps storage data to load) then select music and you can manually delete the podcast from there.

Comment: Sorry, that should be "podcasts" app, not music obviously.  Also, what happens when you try to swipe-and-delete directly from "my podcasts" in podcast app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you pull down on the list of podcast, there is an edit button in the top left corner. the podcast can then be removed by clicking the x

Comment: In ios7 the edit button is gone. Really not liking 7 at all

Comment: @RobR I just checked, and the Edit button is still there in iOS 7. You have to pull down on the grid of podcasts to get it to show up.

Comment: +1. The edit button is visible in the top left in iOS 8 on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked before the public release of iOS7, so I assume you were asking about iOS6 or earlier. However, since it's not tagged for any specific version of iOS, here's the iOS 7 answer.

As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is to put your podcasts in list view (not grid view). Swipe the name of the podcast you want to delete to the left to reveal the red `Delete` button and tap that

[image: annotated screenshot of podcasts.app]

Of course, I would never *actually* delete the Planet Money podcast :)

Answer (score -1):

If you switch the view to list view you can swipe left and delete